# dot net service reference authentication

Tags: wcf, service, reference

Can anyone concisely describe or point me to a resource which explains how to call a service reference and pass in credentials?  I have created the service reference from a wsdl, but I am stuck on how to call it with credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot - I was using the wrong class, need to use the one with Client in the name, eg

MyServiceClient c as new MyServiceClient();

not

MyService c = new MyService();

This allows setting of  the ClientCredentials, eg 
c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "joeblow";